# How to debug mod_ldap in Apache

Tags: apache, apache2, ldap, mod-ldap

I am trying to debug an apache to ldap connection. The Apache server just reply with an Error 500 in the access.log file. I do not have any error in the error.log file.

I have seen that the LDAPLibraryDebug Directive is only available in Apache 2.4 and I am using Apache 2.2. Any ideas on how add more debug messages in the error log?

Comment: Can you get error logs from the LDAP server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add "LDAPLibraryDebug" to a 2.2 server with this debug module:

https://github.com/covener/apache-modules/tree/master/mod_ldap_debug

Answer (score 0):

To debug mod_ldap (and mod_authz_ldap) you need to have both services (Apache and LDAP) in debug mode.
For Apache use configuration parameter in   sequence :

```
LogLevel debug
```

More info available on follow URL https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/apache-logging-basics/

For LDAP service (if you use OpenLdap) stop standard service and start OpenLdap in foreground debug mode with (example):

```
slapd -d 128
```

More info available on follow URL https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/runningslapd.html